# Como puedo dividir una columna de un df pandas

Tags: python, pandas

estoy tratando de dividir una columna de un df en 2 columnas distintas, al aplicar el split(" ") me separa el primer espacio encontrado, pero necesito separar el resto del string. no logro realizarlo el error que obtengo es el siguiente:

```
**>  in _iset_not_inplace
>     raise ValueError("Columns must be same length as key") ValueError: Columns must be same length as key**
```

Como estoy aplicando la separacion de la columna

```
dataset[["Fecha Local / Lugar"]] = dataset[["Fecha Local / Lugar"]].astype(str)

dataset[["Fecha Local", "Lugar"]] = dataset["Fecha Local / Lugar"].str.split(" ")
```

la columna es la siguiente:

```
                                  Fecha Local / Lugar            Fecha UTC Latitud / Longitud Profundidad Magnitud (2)
0   2022-05-03 11:02:5447 km al SO de Mina Collahuasi  2022-05-03 15:02:54    -21.146 -68.960      107 km       3.0 Ml
1   2022-05-03 11:02:5447 km al SO de Mina Collahuasi  2022-05-03 15:02:54    -21.146 -68.960      107 km       3.0 Ml
2   2022-05-03 11:02:5447 km al SO de Mina Collahuasi  2022-05-03 15:02:54    -21.146 -68.960      107 km       3.0 Ml
3   2022-05-03 11:02:5447 km al SO de Mina Collahuasi  2022-05-03 15:02:54    -21.146 -68.960      107 km       3.0 Ml
4   2022-05-03 11:02:5447 km al SO de Mina Collahuasi  2022-05-03 15:02:54    -21.146 -68.960      107 km       3.0 Ml
```

Lo que necesito es que la columna fecha local quede separada de Lugar.

```
Fecha Local                       Lugar
03-05-2022 12:32        47 km al SO de Mina Collahuasi
03-05-2022 12:32        47 km al SO de Mina Collahuasi
03-05-2022 12:32        47 km al SO de Mina Collahuasi
03-05-2022 12:32        47 km al SO de Mina Collahuasi
03-05-2022 12:32        47 km al SO de Mina Collahuasi
```

Comment: Buen día, en el `string` ¿La fecha local y el lugar vienen juntos tal como lo pones en la pregunta? Es decir, tienes la hora y el número 47 juntos, sin espacio entre ellos `11:02:5447` ¿Es correcto?

Comment: @HeytalePazguato así es tal cual lo puse en la pregunta

Comment: Ok, pero entonces no lo puedes hacer con split para buscar espacios, ahora pongo la respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

El problema es que estas intentando dividir la columna con `split()` buscando espacios, el `string` de la columna tiene 7 espacios (En los datos que pusiste, tal vez otras filas tengan más) y estas intentando separarlo en 2 columnas, es por eso que el error te dice, "Estoy generando 7 columnas con el split y tú quieres guardarlas en 2", o en otras palabras, el número de columnas (7) debe ser igual al número de llaves (2)

Si utilizaras el argumento `n` de `split()` entonces puedes indicar cuántas veces vas a dividir el `string`, si pones `n=1` hace una división en el primer espacio y entonces tendrías 2 columnas, pero el primer espacio es después de la fecha, y te quedaría la hora y el lugar juntos

Como la hora (La parte de los segundos) y el número 47 del lugar están juntos no puedes separar con `split()`. Lo que podrías hacer es separar con el número de caracteres en una columna y en otra

Si el formato de fecha y hora siempre es "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" (Como los datos que muestras) entonces siempre va a consistir de 19 caracteres (4 año, 2 mes, 2 día, 2 hora, 2 minuto, 2 segundo, 2 guiones, 2 dos puntos y 1 espacio) por lo que puedes dividir las columnas con esa "regla"

Para el ejemplo utilicé los mismos datos que pusiste en tu pregunta en un archivo que llamo "sample.csv"

```
   Fecha Local / Lugar                                  Fecha UTC               Latitud / Longitud    Profundidad    Magnitud (2)
0  2022-05-03 11:02:5447 km al SO de Mina Collahuasi    2022-05-03 15:02:54    -21.146 -68.960        107 km         3.0 Ml
1  2022-05-03 11:02:5447 km al SO de Mina Collahuasi    2022-05-03 15:02:54    -21.146 -68.960        107 km         3.0 Ml
2  2022-05-03 11:02:5447 km al SO de Mina Collahuasi    2022-05-03 15:02:54    -21.146 -68.960        107 km         3.0 Ml
3  2022-05-03 11:02:5447 km al SO de Mina Collahuasi    2022-05-03 15:02:54    -21.146 -68.960        107 km         3.0 Ml
4  2022-05-03 11:02:5447 km al SO de Mina Collahuasi    2022-05-03 15:02:54    -21.146 -68.960        107 km         3.0 Ml
```

Para obtener la fecha local utilizamos los primeros 19 caracteres

```
df['Fecha Local'] = df['Fecha Local / Lugar'].str.slice(stop=19)
```

Para obtener el lugar utilizamos los caracteres restantes empezando por la posición 19

```
df['Lugar'] = df['Fecha Local / Lugar'].str.slice(start=19)
```

Eliminamos la columna "Fecha Local / Lugar"

```
df = df.drop(['Fecha Local / Lugar'], axis= 1)
```

Y nos queda de esta forma

```
   Fecha UTC             Latitud / Longitud Profundidad Magnitud (2)    Fecha Local         Lugar
0  2022-05-03 15:02:54   -21.146 -68.960    107 km      3.0 Ml          2022-05-03 11:02:54 47 km al SO de Mina Collahuasi
1  2022-05-03 15:02:54   -21.146 -68.960    107 km      3.0 Ml          2022-05-03 11:02:54 47 km al SO de Mina Collahuasi
2  2022-05-03 15:02:54   -21.146 -68.960    107 km      3.0 Ml          2022-05-03 11:02:54 47 km al SO de Mina Collahuasi
3  2022-05-03 15:02:54   -21.146 -68.960    107 km      3.0 Ml          2022-05-03 11:02:54 47 km al SO de Mina Collahuasi
4  2022-05-03 15:02:54   -21.146 -68.960    107 km      3.0 Ml          2022-05-03 11:02:54 47 km al SO de Mina Collahuasi
```

Si deseas cambiar el orden de las columnas podrías crear una lista con el orden que deseas y luego utilizarla para ordenar el `dataframe`

```
cols = ['Fecha Local', 'Lugar', 'Fecha UTC', 'Latitud / Longitud', 'Profundidad', 'Magnitud (2)']
df = df[cols]
```

Ejemplo completo:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')
df['Fecha Local'] = df['Fecha Local / Lugar'].str.slice(stop=19)
df['Lugar'] = df['Fecha Local / Lugar'].str.slice(start=19)
df = df.drop(['Fecha Local / Lugar'], axis= 1)
cols = ['Fecha Local', 'Lugar', 'Fecha UTC', 'Latitud / Longitud', 'Profundidad', 'Magnitud (2)']
df = df[cols]
```

Comment: creo que el problema esta en que en el string hay una etiqueta <br>
<td><a href="/sismicidad/informes/2022/05/149582.html">2022-05-01 07:30:23</a><br>51 km al O de Ollagüe</td> y esto hace que obtenga el string junto tanto fecha y el texto del lugar del sismo.

Comment: @Daxtrox, ya veo. Si la respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas