# separar una cadena de texto en el segundo espacio en blanco pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

Estoy tratando se separar una cadena de texto en el segundo espacio en blanco y que guarde los datos en 2 columnas distintas. con el metodo split solo pude hacerlo en el primer espacio en blanco y no en el segundo, alguien con alguna solucion para esto?

```
2022-05-05 08:38:25 33 km al NE de Cuya
                   ^
Aqui es donde necesito separar la cadena de texto
```

Comment: Y que diferencia habría?

Comment: necesito que la segunda columna comienza en 33 km al NE de Cuya y no en 08:38:25

Comment: Por que la respuesta que te dieron en tu pregunta anterior no sirve para resolver el problema real?

Comment: le quitas el espacio con `.rstrip()`

Comment: @DanteS. no, por eso realizo otra pregunta

Comment: @Christian .rstrip() me elimina todos los espacios en blanco?, o puedo seleccionar solo los que quiero eliminar?

Comment: perdón, era `.strip()`, esto te quita los espacios en blanco al inicio y final de la cadena

Comment: Heltalepasguato dijo en su respuesta que si el formato de la fecha y hora siguen un formato especifico, puedes valerte de separar según la posición 19. Por que eso no te sirve?

Comment: @DanteS. no es mi caso...

Comment: O existe algún motivo por el cual no puedas aplicar la respuesta anterior? Si es así por favor exponla

Answer (score 0):

Estoy seguro que no es la solución mas optima pero creo que consigues lo que buscas con esto:

```
txt = "2022-05-05 08:38:25 33 km al NE de Cuya"

cadena = txt.split(" ", 2)
arr = [[cadena[0] + " " + cadena[1]], [cadena[2]]]
print(arr)
```

Resultado:

```
[['2022-05-05 08:38:25'], ['33 km al NE de Cuya']]
```

Comment: Como dices, tu solución no es la mas optima. Pero eso no es un problema. El verdadero problema sería que tu solución solo aplica a casos donde la cadena tenga siempre la misma cantidad de espacios. Si probases con una cadena con un espacio más, tu solución se saltaría esa ultima parte y con uno menos saltaría un error.

Comment: Sabías que el método `split()` acepta como segundo argumento un número máximo de separaciones?, por lo que podrías hacer `fecha, hora, cadena = txt.split(" ", 2)` y luego ya hacer cualquier tratamiento a los resultados como `.strip()` para quitar espacios en blanco

Comment: Y también tienes el método `join`, para no tener que andar poniendo espacios a mano.

Comment: Utilizados los consejos de los compañeros para mejorar el código

Answer (score 0):

Es simple usando `split` con el parámetro opcional `maxsplit`. Este indica cuantos veces aplicar la separación:

```
test = "2022-05-05 08:38:25 33 km al NE de Cuya"
fecha, hora, resto = test.split(maxsplit=2)

fechaHora = f"{fecha} {hora}"
print(fechaHora)
print(resto)
```

Con `maxsplit=2` queda dividido en tres partes: la fecha, la hora y el resto. La fecha y hora la concatenamos en un solo string usando f-string.

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Otra opción es utilizar el índice del `split()` para formar tus "frases"

Por ejemplo, para tomar los primeros 2 índices, es decir la fecha y la hora

```
s = '2022-05-03 11:02:54 47 km al SO de Mina Collahuasi'
print(' '.join(s.split(' ')[:2]))
```

Esto devuelve:

```
'2022-05-03 11:02:54'
```

Y para obtener lo demás:

```
s = '2022-05-03 11:02:54 47 km al SO de Mina Collahuasi'
print(' '.join(s.split(' ')[2:]))
```

Esto devuelve:

```
'47 km al SO de Mina Collahuasi'
```

Pero si usas este método en un `dataframe` con muchos datos será más lento que el [método que puse en tu pregunta anterior](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/531808/171630), sigo pensando que separar en el caracter 19 sería lo mejor y más eficiente.